# How to set routes for ActiveAdmin manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeadmin

Can I set routes for Active Admin manually?

For example:

```
get '/admin' => 'to#admin'
```

Or in the `initializers/active_admin.rb`, now it's like:

```
config.default_namespace = :locale/:admin
```

can I make something like:

```
config.default_namespace = "/en/my/admin"
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You miss understand `config.default_namespace`, its for the the name of the namespace and not for the routes name. Take a look on https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Switching-locale, that's is what you want to do.